# Web folder content moved up a level - Craft Path settings

Tags: craft3, config

I use subdomains for staging environments. That meant in Craft 2 I had to move the public_html folder content up a level and change

```
$craftPath = '../craft';
```

To:

```
$craftPath = 'craft';
```

I'm getting myself in a bit of a mess how to do this for Craft 3. I've moved the contents of 'web' into the root folder for the subdomain.

I think I have to change these settings

```
define('CRAFT_BASE_PATH', dirname(__DIR__));
define('CRAFT_VENDOR_PATH', CRAFT_BASE_PATH.'/vendor');
```

but it's a bit over my head, so any help to what I change these to would be much appreciated.

My hosting doesn't allow configuring the webserver to point to the /web folder.

Structure:

- index.php
- css
- js
- craftcms

  - config
  - modules
  - storage
  - templates
  - vendor

Answer (score 2):

To replicate what you did in craft 2, you would change your web/index.php to:

```
define('CRAFT_BASE_PATH', dirname(__DIR__,1) . '/nameofthefolderwherecraftlives');
```

The `,1` tells craft to go up **1** level and change `/nameofthefolderwherecraftlives` to well... The name of the folder where craft lives :)

So for what I show you above, your structure will be:

- web

  - index.php
- nameofthefolderwherecraftlives

  - config
  - modules
  - storage
  - templates
  - vendor

It's [here in the docs](https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/config/php-constants.html#craft-base-path).

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks. Makes sense but I don't think I explained throughly. I've updated my post with the structure (no web folder - it's content sits in the root)

Answer (score 1):

Oh I see. Then if the root folder where your index.php lives is let's say `public_html` you could do:

`define('CRAFT_BASE_PATH', dirname(__DIR__) . '/public_html/craftcms');`

Another solution would be to use `__FILE__` instead of `__DIR__` and you could do:

`define('CRAFT_BASE_PATH', dirname(__FILE__) . '/craftcms');`

However, I don't know the implications of the second option. It works for me when I test locally and doesn't break anything but I can't be sure... Maybe the Craft guys could tell us more on this..?

Anyway I hope this gets you up and running :)